# tellg moves after write operation in file

Tags: c++, file-io

Why does tellg() moves after a write operation, I suppose it should be tellp()?

```
std::fstream fs("c:\\log.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
fs << "write";
std::cout << fs.tellg() << std::endl;
fs.close();
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream actually maintains only one pointer, so the read and write pointers are effectively the same. if you want to do reads and writes to the same file, you should maintain your own pointer and do a seek before every read/write operation.

Comment: Why? It doesn't happen to me in stringstream.

Comment: Ah, why? I find questions that ask why? here to be pretty useless. Programming languages are human constructs and could actually have been defined in an infinite number of ways. We are stuck with the one way the designers decided on.

Comment: @George  What on that page supports your "no it doesn't" assertion? My authority is Langer & Kreft - "Bidirectional file streams ... maintain only one joint position indicator".

Comment: Because the get pointer comes from the istream and the put from the ostream. So how can they be the same?

Comment: @parc65 File and memory streams are implemented differently. Memory streams have two position pointer, while file streams have only one.

Comment: @George Sorry, you are wrong. Read Langer & Kreft - http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201183951/?tag=stackoverfl08-20